# How to decrypt a file which is encrypted using GNU privacy assistant in SSIS package

Tags: file, encryption, ssis

I have to decrypt all the files inside a folder using the SSIS package and after that I have to work on those decrypted files.

I have installed GNU privacy assistance in my system which allows to encrypt/decrypt a file manually. But how can I decrypt the files programatically?

Any help or suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Per the [documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpa/), GPA is just a GUI, so have you tried using the command line tools and if so what progress have you made?

Comment: @Kevin Bedell. yes, i have found the way of decrypting the file programetically. but another problem is that it decrypts only those files which is encrypted in the same system. for example if i use the encrypted file from another system it is not decrypting.